# Hibernate can't list Mysql SHOW SESSION STATUS

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
session.createSQLQuery("SHOW SESSION STATUS").list()
```

throws strange exception :

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' not found.
could not execute query
SQLState S0022

But

```
session.createSQLQuery("SHOW SESSION STATUS").executeUpdate()
```

works fine and returns exact size of result list : 291

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("SHOW SESSION STATUS");
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> result = query.list();
```